# Can't INSERT NULL into table (Primary Key)

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, null, primary-key

I want to insert my model to database

```
EventAdditionalSell eas = new EventAdditionalSell();
eas.EventNoteID = en.EventID; (e.g 100 which exists in datatable)
eas.Person = mdl.Person; (string - can be just "")

db.EventAdditionalSells.Add(eas);
db.SaveChanges();
```

And I always get an exception

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EventAdditionalSellID', table '1028_test.dbo.EventAdditionalSells'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

My class:

```
public class EventAdditionalSell
{
        [Key]
        public int EventAdditionalSellID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Kupujący")]
        public string Person { get; set; }

        public int EventNoteID { get; set; }
        public virtual EventNote EventNote { get; set; }
        public virtual List<PaintballItem> PaintballItems { get; set; }
    }
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Is the key set as a Identity column in the database? If not, you need to make it so, or add some function to automatically insert your ID. The Key attribute tells EF not to insert that value itself.

Comment: Try to add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute to `EventAdditionalSellID`